# Blackberry push notifiaction message showing in pop up screen

Tags: blackberry, java-me

have used this link for push notification http://rincethomas.blogspot.in/2012/07/push-notification-in-blackberry.html

the code is running fine and i'm receiving push notification in dialog, but instead of showing the default dialog, i have created my own pop up screen to show push message

but i am getting error in my PushMessageReader.java as you can check that in link. here is my PushMessageReader.java code for pop up screen to show push message

```
public final class PushMessageReader {

    // HTTP header property that carries unique push message ID
    private static final String MESSAGE_ID_HEADER = "Push-Message-ID";
    // content type constant for text messages
    private static final String MESSAGE_TYPE_TEXT = "text";
    // content type constant for image messages
    private static final String MESSAGE_TYPE_IMAGE = "image";

    private static final int MESSAGE_ID_HISTORY_LENGTH = 10;
    private static String[] messageIdHistory = new String[MESSAGE_ID_HISTORY_LENGTH];
    private static byte historyIndex;

    private static byte[] buffer = new byte[15 * 1024];
    private static byte[] imageBuffer = new byte[10 * 1024];

    static Popupscreen popup;
    private static String text;


    /**
     * Utility classes should have a private constructor.
     */
    private PushMessageReader() {
        popup = new Popupscreen();
    }


    /**
     * Reads the incoming push message from the given streams in the current thread and notifies controller to display the information.
     * 
     * @param pis
     *            the pis
     * @param conn
     *            the conn
     */
    public static void process(PushInputStream pis, Connection conn) {
        System.out.println("Reading incoming push message ...");

        try {

            HttpServerConnection httpConn;
            if (conn instanceof HttpServerConnection) {
                httpConn = (HttpServerConnection) conn;
            } else {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Can not process non-http pushes, expected HttpServerConnection but have "
                        + conn.getClass().getName());
            }

            String msgId = httpConn.getHeaderField(MESSAGE_ID_HEADER);
            String msgType = httpConn.getType();
            String encoding = httpConn.getEncoding();

            System.out.println("Message props: ID=" + msgId + ", Type=" + msgType + ", Encoding=" + encoding);


            boolean accept = true;
            if (!alreadyReceived(msgId)) {
                byte[] binaryData;

                if (msgId == null) {
                    msgId = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());
                }

                if (msgType == null) {
                    System.out.println("Message content type is NULL");
                    accept = false;
                } else if (msgType.indexOf(MESSAGE_TYPE_TEXT) >= 0) {
                    // a string
                    int size = pis.read(buffer);
                    binaryData = new byte[size];
                    System.arraycopy(buffer, 0, binaryData, 0, size);   

                    PushMessage message = new PushMessage(msgId, System.currentTimeMillis(), binaryData, true, true );
                    text = new String( message.getData(), "UTF-8" );

                    System.out.println("PUSH MESSAGE================ "+text);
                     try{
                            /*final Dialog screen = new Dialog(Dialog.D_OK_CANCEL, " "+text,Dialog.OK,
                                    //mImageGreen.getBitmap(),
                                    null, Manager.VERTICAL_SCROLL);*/

                            final UiEngine ui = Ui.getUiEngine();

                            Application.getApplication().invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {

                                public void run() {

                                    NotificationsManager.triggerImmediateEvent(0x749cb23a76c66e2dL, 0, null, null);

                                    ui.pushGlobalScreen(popup, 0, UiEngine.GLOBAL_QUEUE);

                                }
                            });

                            //screen.setDialogClosedListener(new MyDialogClosedListener());
                            }

                     catch (Exception e) {
                                // TODO: handle exception
                            }


                    // TODO report message
                }  else {
                    System.out.println("Unknown message type " + msgType);
                    accept = false;
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("Received duplicate message with ID " + msgId);
            }
            pis.accept();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Failed to process push message: " + e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Check whether the message with this ID has been already received.
     * 
     * @param id
     *            the id
     * @return true, if successful
     */
    private static boolean alreadyReceived(String id) {
        if (id == null) {
            return false;
        }

        if (Arrays.contains(messageIdHistory, id)) {
            return true;
        }

        // new ID, append to the history (oldest element will be eliminated)
        messageIdHistory[historyIndex++] = id;
        if (historyIndex >= MESSAGE_ID_HISTORY_LENGTH) {
            historyIndex = 0;
        }
        return false;
    }

    class Popupscreen extends PopupScreen{

        LabelField label = new LabelField("");

        ButtonField Okbutn;

        public Popupscreen(){
            super(new VerticalFieldManager(), Screen.DEFAULT_CLOSE); 

            Okbutn = new ButtonField("ok",ButtonField.FIELD_HCENTER);

            LabelField lbl = new LabelField("SUNRAYS", LabelField.USE_ALL_WIDTH | DrawStyle.HCENTER){
                 protected void paintBackground(net.rim.device.api.ui.Graphics g)
                    {
                        g.clear();
                        g.getColor();
                        //g.setColor(Color.WHITESMOKE);
                        //g.fillRect(0, 0, Display.getWidth(), Display.getHeight());
                        g.setColor(Color.WHITESMOKE);               
                    }
             };


             add(lbl);
             add(label); 
             add(Okbutn); 

             label.setText(text);

             Okbutn.setChangeListener(new FieldChangeListener() {

                public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    close();
                }
            });
             //this.setBackground(BackgroundFactory.createSolidTransparentBackground(Color.WHITE, 80));

            // setBorder(BorderFactory.createSimpleBorder(new XYEdges(),Border.STYLE_TRANSPARENT)); 

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: may i know the error you getting ?

Comment: will you tell me what is popup ?

Comment: popup means i want to open pop up screen as you can see in my above code i posted..,

Comment: i'm getting Nullpointerexception

Comment: your code extends application class. not uiapplication.

Comment: first open the ui application , then push your screen. or if your app is in background, then bring it to foreground, then push your popup screen.

Comment: but is it possible to show the pop up screen in background when i receive push message .., if you look at the example in the link, a dialog box will appear even if my application is in background but my pop up screen is not showing as you can see in my code

Comment: its a global popup. Also its my blog. You do onething Just open your app using code module manager and then push your popup screen.

Comment: hi, i'm new to BB, i have never worked with  code module manager, plz can you guide me

Comment: i added the code in your comment of my blog. just check it

Comment: but i'm not able to find your posted code  on this linkhttp://rincethomas.blogspot.in/2012/07/push-notification-in-blackberry.html

Comment: plz can you post that code here...

Comment: ApplicationDescriptor[] appDescriptors =CodeModuleManager.getApplicationDescriptors(CodeModuleManager.getModuleHandle("push_msg"));
ApplicationDescriptor appDescriptor = new ApplicationDescriptor(appDescriptors[0], new String[] {"push_msg"});
ApplicationManager.getApplicationManager().runApplication(appDescriptor); This will open your application. then you can push your popup screen. 1 Drawback- everytime when u get new message,it will open up app and push screen.

Comment: and one thing you have told me that, the default popup dialog is global popup. it'll show even if our app is in background or in foreground and plz can you explain me that why can not we use that concept with our own Pop up screen to show msg even if our app is in background or in foreground.

Comment: Please any one help me..

Comment: hi, my credentials are expired for push so email for new one and after using new one i'm getting the following error
msg RESPOSE CODE 1:    rc=10002
[0.0] FD Back On
[0.0] msg BPAS rejected registration

Comment: plz tell me what is wrong ?